# How to get your question seen?

Tags: discussion

I posted [a question 14 hours ago but it only got 6 views](https://superuser.com/questions/1033746/skype-audio-becomes-distorted-after-other-programs-make-sounds) before being pushed out of visibility by newer questions.

I asked my question on the product's official community site a few weeks ago but I didn't receive any replies, which is why I posted it here, too.

It is a very popular product that I'm having trouble with, published by one of today's software giants but so far I have been unable to get help with my problem. It seems that Super User is so popular now that "lesser" questions are likely to be overlooked. What else can I do?

Comment: Adding a bounty should help

Comment: @CJDennis Your question still appears on the third page on unanswered questions.  I could comment on your question, I see at least 5 issues with it, that is preventing you from getting an answer.  I would state those problem, but something about your expectation of an immediate answer, has rubbed me the wrong way.  Just keep answering the questions people have for you.

Comment: From the SU help: [What should I do if no one answers my question?](http://superuser.com/help/no-one-answers)

Answer (score 2):

#### Be patient.

Your question is “How to get your question seen?” and then you claim “It seems that Super User is so popular now that "lesser" questions are likely to be overlooked.” These are both misstatements for different reasons.

First, just because you posted a question doesn’t mean you will get an immediate answer. Posting a question simply means you have posted a question to the community. And if someone sees it and has solid advice then they will answer it. In this case, while Skype is a popular product sometimes glitches like this really end up in a “Welp, wait for an update!” scenario because the code is not open source and Microsoft is never really that helpful when it comes to Skype.

Next, the idea that any question here is “lesser” seems a bit silly. Skype is a popular product and Microsoft is a large company. The question is quite valid but it honestly could just be a situation where people who are able to help are just not around or nobody has real specifics.

So my advice? I posted [a comment on your question](https://superuser.com/questions/1033746/skype-audio-becomes-distorted-after-other-programs-make-sounds) requesting slightly more details. This might not speed up you getting a specific fix, but what it can do is provide some improved search ability for the question on this site and on Google. By adding more details someone else as frustrated as you about this issue might search based on those details, trip across this question and add some notes that might be helpful to you and others.

Comment: Thank you for both your replies. I am a member of many SO communities and on the "smaller" ones responses happen quite quickly. I was not trying to bump my question, which your edit to this question seems to have done.

Comment: @CJDennis, `I am a member of many SO communities and on the "smaller" ones responses happen quite quickly. ` - You can go back to them then if you feel the service/response time here is not to your liking

Comment: @Dave http://superuser.com/help/be-nice